plot supremum of a sequence
I try to achieve something similar as in the following picture: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Lim_sup_example_5.png
I arrive at
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
    ymin=-2,
    ymax=2,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=10,
    mark size=1pt
    ]
\addplot[%
    mark=none,
    domain=0:10,
    samples=1010,
    only marks,
    blue!50,
    draw=black] {sin(5*deg(x))*(e^(-x)+1)};
    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Which gives the oscillating sequence. Now I am a bit lost as to how to draw the red parts for the supremum and infimum.

You can't unless you have some kind of time-dependent look-ahead capability. Generally speaking, without making assumptions, you can't even know future values will have increased. // Practically speaking you'd draw the red curves from table or coordinates data, not from a formula (unless you can come up with such a formula, pgfplots can deal with).

@MS-SPO Would it be possible to go backwards?  That is, plot (10-t, sin(5deg(10-t))(e^(x-10)+1)) and track the max and min encountered so far?

Inventive thought +1. However, to my knowledge there is no sup() function implemented. To determine sup(t_back) it’s probably easiest to do on data (this didn’t change). Best options to do that are probably using expl3 or calculating data externally. Also, there will be some minor unwanted effect for the first backward period.

Thanks for the answers. I did it just more or less by hand.

Conceptually, we can do this by going backwards through the graph, tracking the max and min seen so far.  The hard part is implementing that in pgf, for which we use the fact that scatter/@pre marker code looks at every point before it gets plotted.  Another hard part is that it doesn't appear to be possible to change the point's coordinates, so we shift it by the necessary amount: valueWeWant-yValue-2 (-2 because that's how high 0 is above the bottom of the graph).  (Another hard part is that we would not have the correct values at the far right of the graph, as noted in the comments.  So we cheat and use the values that we know to expect.  I tried to have another cycle off to the right to give the values a running start, but couldn't make that work.)
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\def\supy{1}
\def\infy{-1}
\pgfplotsset{
    /pgf/declare function={f(\x) = sin(5*deg(\x))*(e^(-\x)+1);},
    running max/.style={
        point meta rel=per plot,
        visualization depends on={y \as \yval},
        scatter/@pre marker code/.code={
            \ifdim \supy pt < \yval pt
                \global\let\supy=\yval
            \fi
            \scope[shift={(0,\supy-\yval-2)}]
        },
        scatter/@post marker code/.code={\endscope},
        scatter
    },
    running min/.style={
        point meta rel=per plot,
        visualization depends on={y \as \yval},
        scatter/@pre marker code/.code={
            \ifdim \yval pt < \infy pt
                \global\let\infy=\yval
            \fi
            \scope[shift={(0,\infy-\yval-2)}]
        },
        scatter/@post marker code/.code={\endscope},
        scatter
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ymin=-2,ymax=2,xmin=0,xmax=10,
    mark=none,domain=0:10,samples=1010,mark size=1pt,
    legend columns=-1,
    legend style={
        /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm},
        at={(0.5,-0.1)},
        anchor=north
    }]
    \addplot[dotted,black]{\supy}; % these values haven't changed yet
    \addplot[dashed,black]{\infy};
    \addplot[only marks,orange!50,draw=black](10-x,{f(10-x)});
    \addplot[only marks,red!50,running max,draw=red!50](10-x,{f(10-x)});
    \addplot[only marks,blue!50,running min,draw=blue!50](10-x,{f(10-x)});
    \legend{$\limsup x_n$,$\liminf x_n$,$x_n$,$\sup_{m\ge n} x_n$, $\inf_{m\ge n} x_n$}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



I just came up with a manual solution. It utilises a solution from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/354754/17360 to make using the constant functions a bit more handy.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}



\pgfplotsset{
        % use this `compat' level or higher to use the LUA backend for calculation
        % (--> speed improvement)
        % declare your function here ...
        /pgf/declare function={
            f(\x) = sin(5*deg(\x))*(e^(-\x)+1);
                g(\x,\a) = \a;
        },
    }


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
    ymin=-2,
    ymax=2,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=10,
    mark size=1pt,
    legend columns=-1,
    legend style={/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm},at={(0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north}
    ]
    
    
\addplot[%
    mark=none,
    domain=0:10,
    samples=20,
    dotted,
    black,
    draw=black] {g(\x,1)};

\addplot[%
    mark=none,
    domain=0:10,
    samples=20,
    dashed,
    black,
    draw=black] {g(\x,-1)};

\addplot[%
    mark=none,
    domain=0:10,
    samples=1010,
    only marks,
    orange!50,
    draw=black] {f(\x)};

    
\addplot[%
    mark=none,
    domain=0.3:0.455,
    samples=18,
    only marks,
    red!95,
    draw=black] {f(\x)};

\addplot[%
    mark=none,
    domain=0.9:1.055,
    samples=18,
    only marks,
    blue!95,
    draw=black] {f(\x)};



\addplot[%
    mark=none,
    domain=1.568:1.65,
    samples=8,
    only marks,
    red!95,
    draw=black] {f(\x)};
    
\addplot[%
    mark=none,
    domain=2.168:2.25,
    samples=8,
    only marks,
    blue!95,
    draw=black] {f(\x)};




\addplot[%
    mark=none,
    domain=0:0.3,
    samples=3,
    only marks,
    red!95,
    draw=black] {g(\x,1.75)};


\addplot[%
    mark=none,
    domain=0:0.93,
    samples=6,
    only marks,
    blue!95,
    draw=black] {g(\x,-1.4)};



\addplot[%
    mark=none,
    domain=0.458:1.568,
    samples=8,
    only marks,
    red!95,
    draw=black] {g(\x,1.215)};
    
\addplot[%
    mark=none,
    domain=1.058:2.168,
    samples=8,
    only marks,
    blue!95,
    draw=black] {g(\x,-1.115)};
    
    

\addplot[%
    mark=none,
    domain=1.665:2.82,
    samples=8,
    only marks,
    red!95,
    draw=black] {g(\x,1.058)};
    
    
\addplot[%
    mark=none,
    domain=2.265:3.42,
    samples=8,
    only marks,
    blue!95,
    draw=black] {g(\x,-1.05)};


\addplot[%
    mark=none,
    domain=2.9:4.08,
    samples=8,
    only marks,
    red!95,
    draw=black] {g(\x,1.02)};
    

\addplot[%
    mark=none,
    domain=3.5:4.68,
    samples=8,
    only marks,
    blue!95,
    draw=black] {g(\x,-1.02)};
    
    

\addplot[%
    mark=none,
    domain=4.2:5.35,
    samples=8,
    only marks,
    red!95,
    draw=black] {g(\x,1.01)};    

\addplot[%
    mark=none,
    domain=4.8:5.95,
    samples=8,
    only marks,
    blue!95,
    draw=black] {g(\x,-1.01)};    


\addplot[%
    mark=none,
    domain=5.37:6.5,
    samples=8,
    only marks,
    red!95,
    draw=black] {g(\x,1.005)};    
    
\addplot[%
    mark=none,
    domain=5.97:7.1,
    samples=8,
    only marks,
    blue!95,
    draw=black] {g(\x,-1.005)};    

    
\addplot[%
    mark=none,
    domain=6.6:10,
    samples=20,
    only marks,
    red!95,
    draw=black] {g(\x,1)};    
    
\addplot[%
    mark=none,
    domain=7.2:10,
    samples=20,
    only marks,
    blue!95,
    draw=black] {g(\x,-1)};
    
 
 \legend{$\limsup x_n$,$\liminf x_n$,$x_n$,$\sup_{m\ge n} x_n$, $\inf_{m\ge n} x_n$}
    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

And produces the following image:

